# active storage - prevent download - open file in browser when possible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am using `rails_blob_url(o.audio_file)` but it is annoying since url doesn't open file in browser but downloads the file as an attachment (this is not a default browser behaviour for audio files).

I want that browser opens the file however it wants. I do not want to force download file ...

```
rails_blob_url(o.audio_file, disposition: :inline)
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: If it is indeed an audio file, you should probably render a normal HTML view and embed some kind of HTML5 component that takes care of playing the audio fragment. I don't think it will be trustworthy to depend on the browser, because each browser could handle it differently.

Comment: Yes, but if I put the file into /public/song.mp3 (or upload it directly to S3), file is not downloded - it opens up in browser which is default way of serving file and that is also what I want but active storage is making this hard to do and do not know why and how to disable this

Comment: You probably need to look into the content-disposition header... you could probably let the browser render it inline instead of downloading. But please be aware that not every browser (on mobile for instance) deals with it in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to using `rails_blob_url(o.audio_file, disposition: :inline)` you also have to allow the content type.

```
Rails.application.config.active_storage.content_types_allowed_inline += [
  "audio/mp3",
  "audio/mp4",
  "audio/mpeg"
]
```

At this time the default content types are: `["image/png", "image/gif", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/tiff", "image/bmp", "image/vnd.adobe.photoshop", "image/vnd.microsoft.icon", "application/pdf"]` so I had to add all the audio ones.

There's a little bit more info about it [here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-storage)

Comment: Thank you! I was beating my head against a wall for hours on this :)